# In R, how to take the mean of a varying number of elements for each row in a data frame?

Tags: r

So I have a dataframe, PVALUES, like this:

```
PVALS <- read.csv(textConnection("PVAL1 PVAL2 PVAL3
0.1 0.04 0.02
0.9 0.001 0.98
0.03 0.02 0.01"),sep = " ")
```

That corresponds to another dataframe, DATA, like this:

```
 DATA <- read.csv(textConnection("COL1 COL2 CO3
 10 2 9
 11 20 200
 2 3 5"),sep=" ")
```

For every row in `DATA`, I'd like to take the mean of the numbers whose indices correspond to entries in `PVALUES` that are <= 0.05.

So, for example, the first row in `PVALUES` only has two entries <= 0.05, the entries in [1,2] and [1,3]. Therefore, for the first row of `DATA`, I want to take the mean of 2 and 9.

In the second row of `PVALUES`, only the entry [2,2] is <=0.05, so instead of taking the mean for the second row of DATA, I would just use `DATA[20,20]`.

So, my output would look like:

```
MEANS
6.5
20
3.33
```

I thought I might be able to generate indices for every entry in PVALUES <=0.05, and then use that to select entries in DATA to use for the mean. I tried to use this command to generate indices:

```
exp <- which(PVALUES[,]<=0.05, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

...but it only picks up on indices for entries the first column that are <=0.05. In my example above, it would only output [3,1].

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, or have ideas on how to tackle this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your output is correct? The mean of 2 and 9 is 5.5. For the last row, dont you want the mean of 2,3, and 5 (ie 3.3)?

Comment: Whoops - right you are, I'll change it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit funny looking, but this should work

```
rowMeans(`is.na<-`(DATA,PVALUES>=.05), na.rm=T)
```

The "ugly" part is calling `is.na<-` without doing the automatic replacement, but here we just set all data with p-values larger than .05 to missing and then take the row means.

It's unclear to me exactly what you were doing with `exp`, but that type of method could work as well. Maybe with

```
expx <- which(PVALUES[,]<=0.05, arr.ind=TRUE)    
aggregate(val~row, cbind(expx,val=DATA[exp]), mean)
```

(renamed so as not to interfere with the built in `exp()` function)

Tested with

```
PVALUES<-read.table(text="PVAL1 PVAL2 PVAL3
0.1  0.04 0.02
0.9  0.001 0.98
0.03 0.02 0.01", header=T)

DATA<-read.table(text="COL1 COL2 CO3
 10   2    9
 11   20   200
 2    3    5", header=T)
```

Comment: Naming an object 'exp' does _not_ interfere with the `exp` function. People are forever naming their dataframes 'data' or 'df' and neither of those operations affects the operation of the functions with the same names.

Answer (score 1):

I usually enjoy MrFlick's responses but the use of `is.na<-` in that manner seems to violate my expectations of R code because it is destructively modifies the data. I admit that I probably should have been expecting that possibility because of assignment arrow but it surprised me nonetheless. (I don't object to data.table code because it is hones t and forthright about modifying its contents with the `:=` function.)  I also admit that my efforts to improve one it lead me down a rabbit hole where I found this equally "baroke" effort. (You have incorrectly averaged 2 and 9)

```
sapply( split( DATA[which( PVALS <= 0.05, arr.ind=TRUE)], 
                 which( PVALS <= 0.05, arr.ind=TRUE)[,'row']), 
          mean)

        1         2         3 
 5.500000 20.000000  3.333333
```